# Async function in django that returns a json response

Tags: django, asynchronous

I want to create an async function  in django to return a json response  but every time a call the function from ajax call i get 500 error  cooroutine has no attribute get

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.core.serializers import serialize

def _get_data(request):
  context = {}
  poi_ids = request.GET.getlist('poi_ids[]')
  if len(poi_ids)> 0:
    poi_list = serialize('geojson', Poi.objects.filter(id__in=poi_ids).distinct('name'),
      geometry_field='geom',
      fields=('name',))
    context['poi_list']  = poi_list
  return JsonResponse(context)

get_poi = sync_to_async(_get_data, thread_sensitive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To undestand  how async views work in django i created this simple example
in views.py i created the following code

```
import asyncio
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Todo


def _get_todo_data(request):
   context = {}
   data = Todo.objects.all()
   context['data'] =  serializers.serialize("json", data)
   return JsonResponse(context)


get_todo_data = sync_to_async(_get_todo_data, thread_sensitive=True)


def todo_list_view(request):
 context = {}
 template = 'todo/todo_list.html'
 return render(request,template,context)
```

so in frontend  to get all todos as ajax promise  i have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.when($.ajax({
           url: '/todo/get/data/',
           method: 'GET',
           datatype: 'json'
  })).then(function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    console.info(response)
    var data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    console.info(data);
  });
```

})